# Is it common practice in a professional kitchen to have a certain spot for each pan on the pan shelf?

Tags: storage

The seven or so pans are much the same size, it's a small kitchen and they are always kept on that under counter shelf.

Answer (score 1):

It's common practice to stack the same sized pans and/or bowls.  No one want to sort through sizes.  It's less efficient.

Given your comment/clarification...it makes sense to keep pans in the same place all the time as well.  During a busy service, I would want to know where everything is at all times.  Consistency and efficiency are primary considerations.

Comment: No, this guy wants them in just the same spots, there's no need to stack.  I thought it was a bit loopy.  He keeps putting pan lids away in storage because HE doesn't use them :/

Answer (score 1):

I would expect a professional kitchen to store pans in a manner that is **efficient** and **safe**.

Pans must be easy to access, easy to pick up, easy to stack (when they come back from cleaning).

Anecdotal, in open kitchen that I've seen, small pans are close to the cooking stations; often on a shelf above the stations; bigger pans are stacked a little bit further away as they are not used (or rarely) when the kitchen in in production.